# How to modify BER and FER values at Veins project

Tags: omnet++, veins

For days I have been looking for information on how to modify two channel's parameters in Veins. I want to modify the bit error rate and the frame error rate. I have not found how to do this.

Please, can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Veins, the frame error rate (and similar parameters) of the channel is not fixed, but rather an outcome of the topology of the network and the network traffic (collisions, interference). There is no way to manually set the frame error rate to a fixed value.